# Columnizer.js Minimum width? Page crashes, stuck loading going under specific number

Tags: jquery, css, width, loading

So I ran into a problem with the columnizer.js script -> script can be found here https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

You have to set the width of the column with this plugin, if I set the width number to, lets say 20px the page starts to load very long (on localhost), if I go under 20px width the page will be stuck in loading time, it is still loading anyhow and a process is going on; knowing it because my macbook fans starting to turn up going on full speed.

Does anybody know if there is a min-width setting within this script I can change? Or what could cause this behavior?